# Ajax Toolkit modal popup

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, modalpopup

I have built an application that uses Ajax toolkit modal popups. The application tests fine on all browsers run from the local IIS on Visual Studio. When deployed to IIS 8.5 the application works fine on Chrome, FF and Edge - (modal popup showing) however on IE 11 and IE 10 the modal popup does not show.

Does anyone have a hint why this is?

Kai

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser's console?

Comment: I get two errors -  'NotFoundError' - script5022, scriptResource.axd(131,13) and 'Unable to set property 'act Control type' of undefined or null reference scriptResource.axd(180,9)

Comment: It looks like this issue: https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/issues/17 It will be fixed with the next release.

Comment: I figured, meanwhile I went back to ver 15. when do you expect the next release?

Comment: We did not schedule any date yet, but it's likely to happen soon after [this PR](https://github.com/DevExpress/AjaxControlToolkit/pull/117) will be merged.

Answer (score 0):

I have the solution.

1) Donwload html5-dataset.js (https://gist.github.com/brettz9/4093766) and save on folder **/Scripts**

2) add this code on page

```
<asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/html5-dataset.js" />
```